# PIP says it is up to date when I try to update it but then it is not

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

How can I fix this issue? This makes no sense, i guess i have two different python path so python gets confused how can i fix this issue as well?

```
C:\Users\user>pip install pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\user>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (20.0.2)
```

Comment: `pip` is not the same pip as `python -m pip`. The first install command is missing the `—upgrade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different versions of Python (hence 2 different versions of pip) installed.

`pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32`

and

`pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32`

In the first example you did `pip install pip` but in the second `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (The help text gave you a bad advice in this case).

If you want to upgrade the Python 3.8 pip, do `pip install --upgrade pip` or with the full path `c:\users\kayra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: `C:\Users\user>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
c:\users\kayra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I get this error, is deleting the old one enough to only continue using one?

Comment: @KayraUckilinc then did you try running the command `c:\users\kayra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` ?